# grep No such file or directory with envoy.run

Tags: python, grep, python-envoy

I try to build script that execute some grep search in my logs and print the results.
I try to use Envoy because is more easy than subprocess but when I execute grep command it gives me back an error of no such file o directory.

The dir structure is easy:

- . # root of script
- test.py # script file
- web_logs/log/ # dir that contains log to search in

My test.py is easy:

```
import envoy

def test(value):

   search = "grep 'cv="+str(value)+"' ./web_logs/log/log_*"
   print(search) #check of the search string
   r = envoy.run(search)
   print(r.status_code, r.std_out, r.std_err)#check of the command
   response = r.std_out

if __name__ == "__main__":
   test(2)
```

The output is:

```
grep 'cv=2' ./web_logs/log/log_*
(2, '', 'grep: ./web_logs/log/log_*: No such file or directory\n')
```

If i run the same command:

```
grep 'cv=2' ./web_logs/log/log_*
```

I can find the occurrence of the string "cv=2" in the log files.

Where is the error?

**Update after the answers**
The problem is in using of * that envoy cannot explode without use of glob module so I using the subprocess as it is and I try to study better the using of glob module to improve envoy.

The new code I used is:

```
import subprocess

def test(value):

   search = "grep 'cv="+str(value)+"' ./web_logs/log/log_*"
   print(search) #check of the search string
   proc = subprocess.check_output(search, shell=True)
   print proc.split('\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
   test(2)
```

Comment: Does it work if you change `c=2` to a term which doesn't contain an equals sign? I'm unfamiliar with `envoy` so this is definitely a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@baptistemm is actually right in that since you're not running bash as part of your process the globbing is not working.

However what's  happening is a bit deeper.

When you run a sub process it can be done by one of several system services (system calls).

## Short Answer (TLDR;)

Here's the correct way to do this:

```
import envoy

def test(value):

   search = "/bin/sh -c \"grep 'cv="+str(value)+"' ./web_logs/log/log_*\""
   print(search) #check of the search string
   r = envoy.run(search)
   print(r.status_code, r.std_out, r.std_err)#check of the command
   response = r.std_out

if __name__ == "__main__":
   test(2)
```

Running the command as a shell command will take care of globbing.

## Long answer

Whenever a sub process is executed, it eventually gets translated into an execve system call (or equivalent).

In `C` library there're helper functions such as `system(3)` and `popen(3)` which wrap around `execve(2)` to provide easier ways of executing processes. `system` launches a shell and passes its argument as is to `-c` option of the shell. popen does extra magic, kinda like what envoy is doing in python.

In envoy, the argument is parsed for `|` (see `def expand_args(command):`) in the envoy code. and then uses the equivalent of `popen` to execute the processes. `envoy` is essentially  what the shell does with the `|` marker (splits things up across the `|` and then uses popen).

What envoy is NOT doing is interpreting `*` as the shell does, as in expanding it to match files using a `glob` function of some sort.  Bash does. Thus my answer.

A fun exercise would be for you to contribute code to envoy :-) and make it do the globbing.

Comment: Thank you both of you baptistemm and @Ahmed, I chose the Ahmed as right one even the other center the trouble with my code, I update soon my answer with the subprocess use and after I study better the glob trouble I try to modify envoy (even the last update is done a long time ago...)

Answer (score 1):

Why it works in terminal but not in envoy is related to globbing ([bash example](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html)).

When you run in your terminal

```
grep 'cv=2' ./web_logs/log/log_*
```

bash will parse the command line and replace the star character with every occurence of file that match. So if you have `./web_logs/log/log_1` `./web_logs/log/log_2` and `./web_logs/log/log_foo` your command will actually be

```
grep 'cv=2' ./web_logs/log/log_1 ./web_logs/log/log_2 ./web_logs/log/log_foo
```

When you execute the same thing in envoy, that'd different, it won't perform the globing of the files then it'll pass to grep a file named `./web_logs/log/log_*` which doesn't exist, this is actually confirmed by the line you pasted in your question.

```
print r.std_err
'grep: ./web_logs/log/log_*: No such file or directory\n'
```

ps: there is a [glob module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) for python

Comment: The point is that his error is actually in misinterpretation of how envoy.run executes the sub processes, and the fact that it's showing up as a globbing issue is just a side effect.

Comment: While I know the cause I didn't have solution in mind to provide because I don't know envoy.

Comment: I did +1 you ... not sure who -1'd you.

Comment: No problem, don't worry

Comment: Thank you @baptistemm, I try to read more about glob module, in the mean time I resolved with use of subprocess instead of envoy. I used   `search = "grep 'cv="+str(value)+"' ./web_logs/log/log_*"
proc = subprocess.check_output(search, shell=True)
response = proc.split('\n')`